# Vim NerdCommenter: adding a new filetype in vimrc

Tags: plugins, vim

is there a way to define a new filetype comment for NerdCommenter in .vimrc?

It's already working, but it would be more easy to backup config, if I can place this into .vimrc directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NERDCommenter is able to parse `commentstring` option, so if you have only one possible comment marker, you may put the following to the vimrc:

```
augroup SetCMS
    autocmd FileType ocaml let &l:commentstring='(*%s*)'
augroup END
```

This does not allow you to specify alternative commenting style (like `/*%s*/` and `//%s` for C++). In this case you should contact author of NERDCommenter and he will add your filetype into next release. [This is the example of filetype support request.](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues/closed#issue/16)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach from the NERDCommenter help documentation seems to actually be to add the following to your .vimrc:

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'someFiletypeOfYours': { 'left': '#'}
\ }
```

You might also consider contributing a pull request to the project on GitHub, so as to have your new language and its comment delimiters be recognized by default by the plugin.