# Vim Nerdcommenter custom delimiters does not work

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

I am attempting to follow the advice here:

[Vim NerdCommenter: adding a new filetype in vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481070/vim-nerdcommenter-adding-a-new-filetype-in-vimrc)

and here:

[MacVim NERDCommenter, how to specify alternative delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303176/macvim-nerdcommenter-how-to-specify-alternative-delimiters)

When I declare my own CustomDelimiters in my `.vimrc` file, the Nerdcommenter does not appear to recognize them.

I have put the lines

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'blahblah': { 'left': '#'}
\ }
```

Into my `.vimrc`, but whenever I open a file called `a.blahblah`, I still get the default `/*...*/` commenting behavior. If I attempt to use `<Leader>ca`, I am told

"NERDCommenter:Cannot use alternative delimiters, none are specified"

I have moved the above lines to the head and tail of my `.vimrc` file, but I get the same behavior.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `g:NERDCustomDelimiters`, you ask the NERD-Commenter plugin to change the delimiters for some specific *file types*.

Unless you added something for this, `blahblah` is not a known file type, so when you edit `a.blahblah`, no file type will be defined, and the NERD-Commenter delimiters will be the default ones.

After opening a file, you can manually change its current file type by doing:

```
set ft=blahblah
```

Then your example should work.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that vim was not recognizing the file type.